# How to set pragma foreign_key=off for database migration only?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

I *enable* foreign key constraint checking via `pragma foreign_keys=on` in `@sqlalchemy.event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")` connection handler. I now want to run a database migration which must *not* have that pragma enabled:

```
def upgrade_database():
    session = orm.Session(bind=op.get_bind())
    session.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;")  # <<< 1st try
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    op.get_bind().execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;")  # <<< 2nd try
    with op.batch_alter_table("user", schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.get_bind().execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;")  # <<< 3rd try
        batch_op.drop_column("outdated_column")  # <<< this is what I want to do...
```

Disabling the pragma didn't work, `batch_op` still generates an IntegrityError. Only solution seems to not set the pragma in the handler. Then migration succeeds but I'd have to know in advance if I am migrating or running the app.

Is there a way to switch off `foreign_key` pragma *only* for this specific migration (and not the whole app)?

Comment: I just found out that `op.get_bind().execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;")` is in fact working - but only if there is no other previous migration (I actually do two migrations and this is in the 2nd one). So it seems some sort of session problem or somehow depend on how alembic executes multiple migrations. Setting the pragma must be the first thing to do.

Comment: Try to commit after setting pragma.